# Task bar, close, minimize, maximize etc. disappeared on Linux mint cinnamon

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

Yesterday, While logging in to my Linux Mint(cinnamon) I noticed that my task bar has been missing. And when I open any window, there is no close/minimize/maximize button. All this sounds weird to me.

I tried rebooting. No change. I have no issue while logging in using gnome classic. All works.

I did not remember of something that I had changed recently. While digging on the internet for this I just found an [odd question](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=131468) on mint forum. But unfortunately no answers. Can someone show some light into this?

Additional information:

While logging to my system i got window saying /tmp is not present or cannot recover /tmp - i dont remember it.

Hardware:

- Asus P53E
- Core i5-2nd generation
- 4GB DDR3 RAM
- Windows 8 PRO dual boot.

Answer (score 3):

I have the answer. At least, for Linux Mint.

It is not a software problem, it is a configuration problem.

Right click on the task bar. Mine is a charcoal strip on the bottom.

Then click on the *troubleshoot* button and expand it.

Then click *restore all settings to default*.

That's it. I spent several hours researching and experimenting before discovering this. You can do it in under 20 seconds. Good luck!

Comment: I've made some improvements on your answer (you can make *italic* by putting it between two stars), and it looks now so wonderful, that I can't avoid to voting it up! Good luck!

Comment: How does one go about right clicking on a taskbar when the taskbar is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the solution from Tim Hughes:

```
ctrl-alt-t => opens terminal

Entering "cinnamon-settings" then <return> opens System Settings app

Click on the "Panel" icon

Under "General Panel Options" click on "Add new panel"

Location options for the new panel are shown by highlights of the screen
area for each location option. 

Left click on the highlighted area at the bottom of the screen.

Right click on the new panel (has a grey background). Then choose "Troubleshoot"

Click on "Restore all settings to default" and answer "Yes" to the "Are you sure?" query.

The original taskbar should reappear.
```